# expected '}' at end of input when no brackets missing

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

someone please help,, i have no idea why i'm getting these error codes
the code is meant to control an arduino car,, with its directions dependent on what light resistor mounted to it is receiving the most light

```
error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token

   void stop_all(){

                  ^
```

quite new to c++ / arduino please help

```
//motor A---left
int ENA = 5;
int IN1 = 6;
int IN2 = 7;

//motor B---right
int ENB = 10;
int IN3 = 8;
int IN4 = 9;

//setup motorspeed
int motorspeeda = 100;
int motorspeedb = 140;// robot was veering slightly to the left,, increasing left motor speed makes it drive straight

//define light resistor pins
int resistor1 = A0;
int resistor2 = A2;
int resistor3 = A4;

//largest resistor constantly changes but needs to be declared outside of the if statements
int largestResistor = 0;

void setup() {

//initialise pins as outputs
//pins defualt to input so light resistors don't need to be changed
pinMode(ENA, OUTPUT);
pinMode(IN1, OUTPUT);
pinMode(IN2, OUTPUT);
pinMode(ENB, OUTPUT);
pinMode(IN3, OUTPUT);
pinMode(IN4, OUTPUT);

// turn serial port on
  Serial.begin(9600);

//read resistor values from pins
  int res1 = analogRead(resistor1);
  int res2 = analogRead(resistor2);
  int res3 = analogRead(resistor3);


//function for robot to stop
  void stop_all(){
  analogWrite(ENA,LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN1, LOW);
  analogWrite(ENB,LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN3, LOW );
  digitalWrite(IN4, LOW);
      }

//function for robot to go forward
  void forward(){
  analogWrite(ENA, motorspeeda);
  digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH);
  analogWrite(ENB, motorspeedb);
  digitalWrite(IN3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN4, LOW);
    }


//function for robot to go backwards
  void backwards(){
  analogWrite(ENA,motorspeeda);
  digitalWrite(IN2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(IN1, LOW);
  analogWrite(ENB,motorspeedb);
  digitalWrite(IN3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN4, HIGH);
    }

//function for robot to go right
  void turnRight(){
  if(millis() < 600){
  analogWrite(ENA,motorspeeda);
  digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH);
  analogWrite(ENB,motorspeedb);
  digitalWrite(IN3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(IN4, LOW);
      }
      else if(millis() < 1500){
        forward();
        }
        else{
          stop_all();
          }
  }

//function for robot to go left
  void turnLeft(){
    if(millis() < 600){
      analogWrite(ENA,motorspeeda);
      digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
      digitalWrite(IN1, LOW);
      analogWrite(ENB,motorspeedb);
      digitalWrite(IN3, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(IN4, LOW);
      }
      else if(millis() < 1500){
        forward();
        }
        else{
          stop_all();
          }
  }

  }

void loop(){

if(millis() < 30000){ //if less than 30 secs elapsed run code,, otherwise run stop function
turnLeft();

}


else{stop_all();}
}
```

Comment: Functions inside functions should not be used. When it tries to call `stop_all` on the line you refer to, it doesn't know what `stop_all` is.

Comment: Why do you attempt to nest functions inside the `setup` function? Nested functions are not allowed in C++, and even if they were then they would be accessible in that scope only.

Comment: It looks to me like you're trying to put a function definition *inside* another function. You just can't do this in `c++`!!

Comment: It's much easier to resolve with proper indentation. (Sorry, no offense: What you exposed is a mess - hard to check by eyes. I copied your code into VS2013 and applied auto-indentation.) It uncovered that you forgot the `}` after `setup()` (just before `void stop_all()`).

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to define functions inside functions.

You cannot do that.

Stop doing that.

Define your functions at namespace scope instead.

If it was a mistake, due to a missing `}`, that's because you have terrible indentation.

Indent your code properly so that you can spot this.

Answer (score 1):

You just missed the  } to close your setup() function.